# Bayesian statistics: Inferring a true value for test sensitivity and specificity

Tags: bayesian, accuracy, diagnostic

Based on a data set I found a sensitivity (.82) and specificity (.88) for a diagnostic test bases on a *n*=257 sample. However, I wonder whether I can generalize these numbers.

I thought this was very much the same question as inferring a succes rate in a binary proces (*k* successes in *n* trials) using a binomial distribution. But I doubt that running two Bayesian parameter estimations (for sensitivity and specificity respectively) is really the best way to go. Does anyone have an idea how to best approach this issue, or maybe it is just unnecessary.

Comment: This paper might be relevant: Andrew Gelman, Bob Carpenter, Bayesian Analysis of Tests with Unknown Specificity and Sensitivity, Journal of the Royal Statistical Society Series C: Applied Statistics, Volume 69, Issue 5, November 2020, Pages 1269–1283, https://doi.org/10.1111/rssc.12435